# Can the existence of $\omega$ be derived from this alternate axiom of infinity?

Tags: set-theory, infinity, ordinals, axioms

Suppose we use the following version of the axiom of infinity in ZFC:

$$\exists x:(\varnothing\in x)\wedge(\forall y\in x:\exists z\in x:y\in z).$$

In words, there is set containing the empty set, in which each member is contained in another member. Is this strong enough to prove the existence of a limit ordinal, the smallest of which can then be defined as $\omega?$

Comment: (The linked duplicate asks about $x=\bigcup x$ whereas your question just requires $x\subseteq \bigcup x$, but the answers still work for your question.)